# Maven isn't installing properly

Tags: maven, installation

I've tried everything I could find on this topic, yet I'm not able to install Maven.

I'm at the following point:

1. I have java installed
2. I unzipped the files from the apache website
3. I have set up environment variables and added requirement parameters to the path (had to use the escape character in the path, because of the space in Program Files folder name: C:\Program^ Files\apache-maven-3.6.3)

what could be the problem?

[cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/podoZ.png)

Comment: so is it running when you use the full path to it?

Comment: Have you set the environment variables in. the cmd line or via GUI and most important have you closed the cmd and reopened...Apart from that I doubt that you have to use a escape character...

Answer (score 0):

From the attached image all requirements are OK. Try one of those two solutions:

1. Close the CMD window and reopen it (if you didn't this already).
2. Restart your computer in in order to apply the environment variables you've just added.

Comment: The restart of the computer is not necessary only close all existing instances of the command line and reopen them..